# How to set a RelativeLayout with transparent background as a View in a ProgressDialog in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout to set as as View in a ProgressDialog, this layout must be with transparent background, in other android versions it is OK but in android 5.0 the RelativeLayout never shows with transparent background, I have tried lots of approaches but could not achieve that.

progress_dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <com.android.library.circleprogress.ArcProgress
        android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        custom:arc_bottom_text="Updating..."
        custom:arc_bottom_text_size="14dp"
        custom:arc_finished_color="@color/corNova"
        custom:arc_progress="0"
        custom:arc_stroke_width="15dp"
        custom:arc_text_color="@color/branco"
        custom:arc_unfinished_color="@color/corFinalizada" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTituloDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/arc_progress"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Aguarde..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#FFA800"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewStartTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textViewTituloDialog"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:text="10:45:23"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/branco"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java code to set the layout as a view the ProgressDialog:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_dialog, null);
    mTextViewStartTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewStartTime);
    arcProgress = (ArcProgress) view.findViewById(R.id.arc_progress);
    arcProgress.setProgress(0);
    setCancelable(false);
    setContentView(view);
}
```

**Result in Android 5.0 (see the white background in the centre of the screen):**

[image]

**Result in Android < 5.0:**

[image]

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

In Android 5 a dialogFragment seems to have a background as well. You can change this by calling this line in your Dialog class in onViewCreated()

```
    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent)));
```

Comment: There is no such method getDialog() in ProgressDialog, nor onViewCreated()

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem passing a style in the constructor of my ProgressDialog extended class, as following:

```
    public class ArcProgressBar extends ProgressDialog {

        ArcProgress arcProgress;
        Context mContext;
        TextView mTextViewStartTime;
        Date mStartTime = null;
        private String mMessage;

        public ArcProgressBar(Context context) {
            super(context, R.style.TransparentProgressDialog);
            this.mContext = context;
        }
...
```